# Rails Keycloak gem with redis cache store throws ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieOverflow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, session-cookies, keycloak, redis-cache

I am using Keycloak gem in my Rails application. As per the keycloak documentation, keycloak uses cookies. In my application, I am using Redis cache store to store these cookies.

```
config.session_store :cache_store, key: ENV['APP_SESSION_KEY']
```

It throws the below

```
raise CookieOverflow if options[:value].bytesize > MAX_COOKIE_SIZE

ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieOverflow
```

If I use **active_record_store** it works fine. But I really need to use **redis_cache_store**.

How can I handle this?

Comment: did yiu found a solution?

Comment: No...not yet...

Comment: i'm having same error, did you found the solution?